# Virus scanner causing a slow application load

Tags: windows, antivirus

I've created a C# application used to deploy a very specific set of applications for a client. This application contains all resources required to do a full deployment of our entire application suite in a single executable, per the client's request - Compressed before embedding.

However, this application is very large (150mb) and every time it starts, it triggers a virus scan from Windows Defender or the client's AV. This causes it to take excessively long to load, upwards of 5 minutes.

Is there a way to sign or otherwise whitelist my application so the virus scanner won't scan it when it's loaded? The application changes its signature on each deployment as the contents change. I've tried whitelisting the directory it lives in, whitelisting the file path, but regardless the virus scanners keep triggering.

I have confirmed that it is a virus scanner by the following actions:

1) When the application is launched, the virus scanner process consumes an entire CPU core

2) Putting a Debugger.Launch() call as the first LOC in the application doesn't get called for a few minutes

2) After disabling the virus scanner, the application loads in under 5 seconds.

Unfortunately, disabling the virus scanner isn't an option on the client side. I use it locally when developing the deployment application, but turning it off - or even suggesting such - on a client's machine would not go over well, and for good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AV behavior isn't that unusual, as your application exhibits major signs of a virus: compressed resources that are being unpacked. The AV product of course doesn't know how your program is compressed, so it must spend quite a bit of time trying multiple approaches at unpacking to establish that none of those produce harmful code.

Path whitelisting is not reliable; any virus that would manage to overwrite a whitelisted executable would bypass the AV.

I'd just put the problem back with the client. They ask for a rather unusual form of executable, and that is **exactly** what the AV is guarding against.

Comment: Is it really that unusual? A MSI is just a packed executable as well, but our team determined that rolling our own deployment would be quicker and more flexible than dealing with a MSI package.

Comment: @MichaelSchultz: Except that your AV product will know what an MSI is, and how it should be scanned.

Comment: Alright, I'll convey this to the client. It makes sense, and is what I expected regardless. Thanks.